# Send the posted form data to another site using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new for Ruby on rails. I need to pass one website form data's to be redirected another website form's using Ruby on Rails. is it possible?
Anybody can help me.

Example:

I filled Contact form details in my website. To be set all form inputs details to destination website's contact form when i submit in my contact form.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can.
You must only add the url to the form helper.

```
<% form_for :url => 'http://example.com' do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```